# bash script text replacement of 1 character placeholder repeated x times with zero padded number

Tags: regex, string, bash

For a bash script - say I have an input of a text with a 'place holder' for a number in this format:
    [V] or [VV] or [VVV] or [VVVV], etc.
Each 'V' character inside the square brackets represents a place holder for 0 (zero) padding.

Thus, if variable (integer) - NUM=17, it should replace e.g. [VVV] 'place holder' in the text as '017', e.g. [VVVVV] as '00017', etc., and single [V] as '17' - a full number, without padding.

Code example:

```
NUM=17

TXT="The version of the new set will be: [V] - after your changes."

# - this is the 1 line I used for the replacement
#   (escaping the square brackets with \)

RESULT="${TXT//\[V*\]/$NUM}"

echo "$RESULT"

# Returns: "The version of the new set will be: 17 - after your changes."
```

My solution is very basic and has problems: It does replace [V], [VV], etc. with $NUM, but it also replaces anything like  [V xxx].

I need to make sure that only 'V' characters are considered as the only valid placeholder, thus - [V] or [VV] or [VVV] or [VVVV], etc. and entries like [Vxxx] are ignored.

I would also appreciate a good idea on counting the 'V' characters inside the input text, so I can apply the 0 (zero) padding.

Code example:

```
LEN= # get the length of the [VVVVV] place holder from $TXT to var. LEN - please advise
RESULT=${TXT//[V*]/$(printf '%0'"$LEN"'d' $(( 10#$NUM )))}
```

I appreciate any ideas to make this work and simple.

Thank you.

Comment: Does running a Perl program from a Bash script count?  I'd be very inclined to do it that way.

Comment: `LEN=$(echo "$TXT" | awk '{match($0,/\[VV*\]/); print RLENGTH-2}' ` might help, but it should be possible wrap both steps into 1 awk process (`printf '%0'RLENGTH-2...`) . This assumes only 1 `[VVV*]` block per line. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the hint RBH.

Here is a solution I came us with; do you guys see anything wrong with this?:

Code sample:

```
NUM=17
TXT="The version of the new set will be: [V];  Format 1: [VVV] Format 2: [VVVV] Format 3: [VVVVVVVVV]"
echo $TXT
V_LIST=$(echo "$TXT" | grep -o '\[V*\]' | sed -e "s/\[//g" -e "s/\]//g")
for V_ITEM in $V_LIST; do
    TXT=${TXT//\[$V_ITEM\]/$(printf '%0'"${#V_ITEM}"'d' $(( 10#$NUM )))}
done
echo $TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your first problem, you can use the following command:

```
RESULT=$(echo "$TXT" |sed -r "s/\[V+\]/$NUM/")
```

This sed command would replace the zero or more occurrence of `V` after `V` inside `[]`